# php: Request succeeds with cUrl, but fails with Guzzle

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I'm trying to use Guzzle in my project to read a value from a URL. The requested url only returns a number, no html header, body or anything. AT first I just used curl to read it, and already figured out I needed to set 2 extra cUrl options to do a succesfull read. My code looked like this, and worked like a charm:

```
$ch = curl_init();  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.2.5/temp');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  

echo $value = curl_exec($ch);
```

Now that I am moving towards using guzzle, I thought I would be ok if I would just use the same cUrl options, so I created this code:

```
$client = new Client( );

$res = $client->request('GET','http://192.168.2.5/temp',['connect_timeout' => 10,'curl' => [CURLOPT_HEADER => 0, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true]]);
echo $Value = $res->getBody()->read(1024);
```

However, this code is giving me this error:

> RequestException in CurlFactory.php line 187: cURL error 0: The cURL
>   request was retried 3 times and did not succeed. The most likely
>   reason for the failure is that cURL was unable to rewind the body of
>   the request and subsequent retries resulted in the same error. Turn on
>   the debug option to see what went wrong. See
>   https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47204 for more information. (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: I had the same issue, I fixed this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323867/url-error-0-the-curl-request-was-retried-3-times-and-did-not-succeed/47232837#47232837

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me (using guzzle 6.2.0):

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET','http://google.com');
echo $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

Alternatively, take a look at this post, and check if your server returns somthing similar, that may cause the problem.

https://www.bountysource.com/issues/32019967-breaking-change-in-guzzle-6-when-receiving-a-204-no-content-response-with-no-body

Comment: sure that works, the problem is that I'm doing a http request to a service that will only give me a number, nothing else. This seems to be difficult for guzzle / cUrl

Comment: What content-type is your service using in its responses?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html

Comment: I just did a quick test with lumen acting as the service, returning only an int. No problems. Something about your service response is probably getting in the way for guzze. If you dont want to change your service, consider using guzzle versions prior to 6, those might not be as strict.

Comment: It sounds like the response might not be providing information as expected.  What happens when you utilize curl from the command line to perform a transaction?  @akrabat has a great post on displaying the contents of curl's request / response here: https://akrabat.com/view-header-and-body-with-curl/   The error you are receiving is an indication that you are not receiving a / the response as expected.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` because I found this question looking for answers to the same problem.

Eventually got my answer at the bottom of this Github issue: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/2048

TL;DR – Guzzle is clobbering `CURLOPT_FILE` and `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` when `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is set; more details in [Reading curl request progress headers with Guzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52926828/reading-curl-request-progress-headers-with-guzzle/52930054#52930054)