# URL error 0: The cURL request was retried 3 times and did not succeed

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl, ssl-certificate, php-curl

I am working on a project that is hosted on Google App Engine, and using app_devserver for local development. At the start I had problems with certificates but when I finally got over that error I am getting this new error

I am using Windows 10 and PHPstorm for development.

Error:

> Message: cURL error 0: The cURL request was retried 3 times and did
>   not succeed. The most likely reason for the failure is that cURL was
>   unable to rewind the body of the request and subsequent retries
>   resulted in the same error. Turn on the debug option to see what went
>   wrong. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47204 for more information.
>   (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Looks like this error is saying that the request is made and successfull but the body could not be resolved or parsed? How can I resolve it?

This is my PHP code if needed: (simple call to tag manager api v2)

```
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('service_account.json');

    $client->setApplicationName("gtmdocx");
    /*$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.readonly',
                        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.manage.accounts',
                        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.edit.containers']);*/
    $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.readonly']);
    $service = new Google_Service_TagManager($client);
    $results = $service->accounts->listAccounts();


    echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($results).')';
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue with google api.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup what operating system are you using, and IDE ?

Comment: Windows and no ide.

Comment: I just saw that the reply under worked for you by modifying sink path?

Comment: I haven’t tried that yet, but yes. The path permissions was my issue and using SINK fixes that.  I just did it a different way.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly this problem using the Google Drive app, after hours trying to find a solution, I got it to work using the GuzzleHttp sink option

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
// ... Client Configuration

$httpClient = new Client([
    'sink' => 'path_to_any_temp_file',
    'base_uri' => $client->getConfig('base_path'),
]);
$client->setHttpClient($httpClient);
```

Worth the try.

Comment: Very nice!  After hours of searching and debugging, I found the root cause and I️ ended up modifying Guzzles source directly to use a temp.txt file.  This is obviously much better.

Comment: dude.... you have saved me from alot of frustration. thank you so much man. sending 3 years of hugs and thanks your way.