# The cURL request was retried 3 times and did not succeed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, runtime-error, guzzle

I'm currently developing a rest API call using (Guzzle client / Laravel) to a custom API. I have tried this several times by adding wrong body. I'm getting the following error

> cURL error 0: The cURL request was retried 3 times and did not succeed. The most likely reason for the failure is that cURL was unable to rewind the body of the request and subsequent retries resulted in the same error. Turn on the debug option to see what went wrong. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47204 for more information. (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Following are the details of my development environment:

```
 Language : php,
 Framework : Laravel 5.4,
 Client : Guzzle,
 OS : Ubuntu 16.04
```

I would like to know the reason behind this

Please kindly assist me on this matter,

Thanks

following is my code

```
{
    $headers = [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$this->accessTocken,
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
            ];

            $Body = [
                'method' => 'AndroidApp',
                'msisdn' => '94777400725',
            ];

            $client = new Client();

            $response = $client->post( $this->url, ['headers'=> $headers, 
             'json'=> $Body]);
}
```

Comment: It seems you need to configure local SSL.

Comment: Another api call is working before this api call to the same server. token creation is working correctly. second api call giving the above error

Comment: Have you checked laravel.log file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL error 0: The cURL request was retried 3 times and did not succeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323867/url-error-0-the-curl-request-was-retried-3-times-and-did-not-succeed)

Comment: Check your webserver's error log as it usually contains a more detailed reasoning.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu there is nothing in the log file

Comment: Can you post your request code?

Comment: Please see the end of the question. thanks

Comment: @xcy7e there is nothing in the nginx error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$response->getBody()->rewind();

worked for me

Comment: can you share full code? where did you use $response->getBody()->rewind();  Mine is breaking on the $client->post[...]