# Reading curl request progress headers with Guzzle

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

When calling curl with php, I'm able to hook callback on `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION` and read headers during the request progress using `curl_multi_getcontent($handle)`

```
$handle = curl_init()
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false)
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true)
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, function($handle) {
   $response = curl_multi_getcontent($handle);
   // some logic here
})
curl_exec($handle)
```

How can I do that with Guzzle?

The problem is that I cannot use `curl_multi_getcontent($handle)` without setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true`.

But when I set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to guzzle' curl config, I can read headers in progress function `$response = curl_multi_getcontent($handle);` However the response stream contains empty content.

```
$request->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents(); // always outputs ""
```

Edit:
I have made this change https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/pull/2173 so I can access handle in progress callback with progress settings:

```
'progress' => function($handle) {
   $response = curl_multi_getcontent($handle);
   // some logic here
})
```

That works as long as `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is `true`. However as I mentioned earlier, the response contents is `""` then.

Answer (score 0):

There is a progress request option.

```
// Send a GET request to /get?foo=bar
$result = $client->request(
    'GET',
    '/',
    [
        'progress' => function(
            $downloadTotal,
            $downloadedBytes,
            $uploadTotal,
            $uploadedBytes
        ) {
            //do something
        },
    ]
);
```

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#progress

Comment: Yes but that doesn't solve how to read headers there and also read response. I have managed to get Handle there via change I implemented to Guzzle https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/pull/2173 so I can read headers during request progress as mentioned with this line `$response = curl_multi_getcontent($handle);`. But then `$request->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents()` is empty (`""`).

Comment: Is it an option for you to use PSR-7 streams in Guzzle?  What happens when you cast the getBody() response to a string?

Comment: It's empty. I have found the answer already. Posting soon. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution or rather an explanation why it is happening.

Guzzle by default sets `CURLOPT_FILE` option when no custom sink is defined (or `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` when sink is defined but that doesn't really matter actually).

However, setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true` negates both of those options -> they're not applied anymore.

Two things happen then after setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`:

1. Response can be read in `PROGRESSFUNCTION` with `$response = curl_multi_getcontent($handle)`. For that this Guzzle modification is necessary https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/pull/2173
2. Response is returned when Guzzle calls `curl_exec($handle)` as return value of this call. But Guzzle doesn't assign it to any variable because it expects that the response is not returned there but through `WRITEFUNCTION` that was however neutralized by setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`.

So my solution is not the cleanest one but I don't find any other way to go around it with Guzzle. Guzzle is simply not built to be able to handle that.

I forked Guzzle. Then created custom Stream class that behaves like default sink -> that writes to `php://temp`. And when my custom Stream class is set as sink I write the result of `curl_exec` into stream:

```
$result = curl_exec($easy->handle);
$easy->sink->write($result);
```